# jQuery val function after save and uploading again it's deleting the old values and uses the new ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an image uploader and I have the following problem.

I got an hidden field called `imgIdInput`.
The first time when I add the images and get the ids and put them inside the value of my hidden input field it's working fine.

After that I am saving it inside PHP and when I come back to edit it and add some more images, the old ones inside the `imgIdInput` attr values are getting deleted and the new ones are getting uploaded.

What I want is to keep the values inside ImgIdInput.val and add the new ones after with a comma.(array)

See code:

```
        attachments.map(function(attachment){
            attachment = attachment.toJSON();
            // Send the attachment URL to our image input field
            imgUl.append(
              '<li id="'+attachment.id+'" class="listitem">'    
            + '<img id="'+attachment.id+'" src="'+attachment.url+'" class="gallery-thumbnail" alt="'+attachment.title+'"/>'
            + '<a class="delete-img" href="#"><span class="dashicons dashicons-no"></span></a>'
            + '</li>');
            attachmentids.push(attachment.id);
            imgIdInput.val(attachmentids);
        });
```

Hopefully someone has a solution.

The problem is after my PHP save the values are perfectly saved. And when I add some new images, I get the new values I want to keep the old values as well that's the whole problem.

Comment: you don't show the declaration of `attachmentids`. It must be an array since you're doing a `.push()`, so you probably want to do something like `imgIdInput.val(attachmentids.join(','));`, because a value for a hidden input should be a string, not an array.

Comment: The thing is after reopening the frame i want to keep the old values inside the array, what's now happening is after i do upload them and i do save them it's deleting the old values inside the imgidinput and its replacing them with the new attachmentids i want something like imgIdInput.val(old attachmentids) + imgIdInput.val(new attachmentids)

Comment: I've told you as much as I can based on the code fragment you've provided. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

val() replaces the current value, if you want to append on it, try it like this:

```
imgIdInput.val( imgIdInput.val()+attachmentids)
```

or even simpler with vanilla javascript (let's suppose your imgIdInput is not a jquery object)

```
imgIdInput.value+=attachmentids
```

Comment: he wants a comma separated list in the hidden. you're not adding a comma

Comment: The problem is after my php save the old values are getting lost and when i do add some new images i do get the new values i want to keep the old values as well that's the hole problem.